# R: Assign the count of rows that meet a condition in a vector to a variable

Tags: r

Using R, I'd like to get the count of rows that match my condition (in this case < 2M) and put that count into a variable.

```
library(VGAM)
DBlah <- rpareto(100,1000000,1)
blahCount <- str(DBlah[DBlah <= 2000000]) 
blahCount #returns null
```

I'm 2 weeks in learning R so I'm sure this is very simple.

Comment: `length(which(DBlah <= 2e6))`

Comment: Actually, you were almost there yourself. Should have used `length` instead of structure: `length(DBlah[DBlah <= 2000000])`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks - also thanks for the table header tip below. Great to  add that to what I've learned so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum`:

```
 sum(DBlah <= 2000000)
```

Or `table` to get the reparation of >= and <:

```
table(DBlah <= 2000000)
```

Comment: or `xtabs(~DBlah < 2e6)` if you want a nice table header :)

Comment: sum works because
`DBlah <= 2000000` returns a Vector of `TRUE`and `FALSE`.
In R `TRUE` is equivalent to 1 and `FALSE` to 0.

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know how it works. That'll come in handy I'm sure.